# Fast checking of continuity between outlets

Tags: wiring, receptacle

We want to check if two outlets are on the same circuit with correct connections.  A quick/dirty way is to insert an extension cord into one of the outlets and then stick  the probes of an ohmmeter into the female side of the extension cord on one end and into the second outlet receptacles on the other.  That is error prone (contact slips) and takes time.

I would like a quicker (/safer) and repeatable way.  I had found [reddit thread: continuity between receptacles](https://www.reddit.com/r/electrical/comments/qd0vv4/continuity_between_receptacles/) but it did not provide any useful alternative.   One thought is to cannibalize two cheap extension cords: retain the male ends, chop off the females, cut open the wires and attach the ohmmeter leads to them. This would need to be done for each of the wires within the cable. Testing would be done with the circuits *off*.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Would need to be sure both outlets do not have power, do think ohm meters do not like 120 volts going though them.  Think there are tools that find unknown breakers for circuits/outlets.  Breaker finder/checkers?

Comment: @crip659 yes I added to the quest1ion about the circuits being off at the time

Comment: When you say "continuity between outlets" are you looking to see if they're on the same circuit? If so, just turn off the breaker for one and see if the other still has power or not.

Comment: @FreeMan  I think maybe he trying to find if they are MWBC or split outlets.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem with the original but a cheaper alternative might be to get a couple of replacement plugs (with or without cables and then attach the probes to them as needed.  Seems less wasteful than trashing two extension cords.

Comment: You can see if they are on the same circuit by turning the breaker off and plugging in a lamp.  That much seems obvious so it's likely there is more to your question than you have stated.   What is "correct continuity"?  What are you actually wanting to do?

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure how much faster it could be than to plug in an extension cord and put the probe of your meter into the female end of the socket. Sounds like a solution in search of a problem. If you're alligator clamping to some bare, stranded wires sticking out of the end of the cut extension cord and around the slick metal of the meter's probe, sounds like there's great opportunity for the clip to slip off, while if it's inside the socket, it should be reasonably well held in place.

Comment: Frankly, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). _Why_ do you need to know if there is "correct continuity" (whatever "correct continuity" is) between two outlets? What is the problem you're attempting to diagnose by determining this?

Comment: Now you're asking about "correct connections", but that's still unclear. Do you mean that you want to confirm that the hot is wired to the shorter blade of the receptacle, the neutral is wired to the longer blade, and the ground is wired to the round pin? What does "correct" mean to you?

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, as already explained in another answer, either two outlets are on the same circuit and one breaker turns both outlets on and of, or they are on two different circuits and they are controlled by different breakers. If they are on the same circuit and things work properly then, by definition, there is continuity on each of the wires. There are a few exceptions:

- High resistance

This is perhaps the biggest concern because it can lead to fires, as well as cause many devices to not function properly. If there is a high-resistance connection, such as from a back-stab gone bad or a loose wire on a screw or in a wire nut, then there will be high resistance which leads to heating and fires. Unfortunately, these are often hard to find with a simple continuity test because there is often *enough* of a connection that a simple test (low-current device plugged in, or a multimeter voltage (with power on) or continuity test (between two outlets with power off) will work just fine. In many of these cases, it is only under a high current load that the problem appears.

- Miswired connections

If a circuit is wired incorrectly, you may have things wrong such as neutral wires mixed up between circuits or hot/neutral reverse. In the case of mixed up neutrals, a continuity test may not really give you the answer because normally (in the US) neutrals are all tied together at the panel and not disconnected by breakers (GFCI or AFCI breakers may be different) so you would see continuity on the neutrals even if they are mixed up.

Hot/neutral reverse is one situation that you could diagnose by checking continuity between hot on two receptacles and between neutral on two receptacles. But a simple 3-bulb tester would diagnose it (assuming that is the only problem) much more easily and much more safely. If you check continuity (resistance) between two hots and one of them turns out to be neutral and power is on you'll have a big surprise. If you check continuity and power is off it will show an open circuit but you won't have any idea why.

Ground continuity is also an issue. But again, there are easier ways to check that, and the problem of a ground used as a neutral (really bad) or a neutral used as a ground (bad for different reasons) where typically neutral and ground are tied together (either in the appliance, such as a dryer with a 3-wire connection, or in the receptacle) will basically look OK in a continuity check because neutral and ground are tied together at the main panel in a properly functioning electrical system.

Answer (score 1):

> We want to check if two outlets are on the same circuit

You do that by plugging a lamp, radio or other obviously on/off item into each outlet, turning the devices on, then turning off the breaker that you expect controls the outlets.

If both devices shut off when you turn off the breaker, then you're confirmed they're on the same circuit. If one remains on, then that outlet is on another circuit. If they both remain on, you've turned off the wrong breaker.

> with correct continuity

You're going to have to define what that means. *Correct* continuity is not a thing that's normally checked for. Either there is electrical continuity between two locations in a circuit or there isn't.